# Mackbook safari location ask again and again even I allowed the permission

Tags: google-maps, safari, geolocation

I am using location detection code at my website, it works correctly for chrome and firefox but when I checked it on MacBook safari and reload the page it's asking again and again even I allowed the location. When I reload the page, all the time it's asking for the location. This is my Code:-

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   getLocation();
});

function getLocation() {
   if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        // Success function
        showPosition, 
        // Error function
        null, 
        // Options. See MDN for details.
        {
           enableHighAccuracy: true,
           timeout: 5000,
           maximumAge: 0
        });
    } else { 
    console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {

   console.log("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not about your code. Change Safari Preference to prompt location service for each website only one time.

Comment: Nader14y and where this Safari preference setting comes in the iPhone safari browser?

Answer (score -1):

Go to **Safari** -> **Preferences** -> **Location**.  Websites that access your browser are listed on the right.  Select **Ask**, **Deny** or **Allow** for each website.